# How to reset Control value?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make a control where we can enter multiple player with tag and their score.

But when we click on my AddPlayer Button I create a player then I need to reset the form control value to default.

I've tried a lot of things but nothing works .... it never changes the view value.

Here is the code:

```
addPlayer(form: ControlGroup) {
    var player = new Player();
    player.tag = form.value.tag;
    player.name = form.value.name;
    player.score = form.value.score;

    // nothing work
    form.value = null;
    form.value.tag = null;
    form.value.tag = '';

    this.playerService.addPlayer(player.tag, player.name, player.score);
    this.newplayer.next(player);
}
```

Here is the html

```
<form (submit)="addPlayer(playerForm)" [ng-form-model]="playerForm">
    <div class="form-group" [class.has-error]="!playerForm.find('tag').valid && playerForm.find('tag').touched">
        <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
            <label for="tag">Tag: </label>
        </div>

        <input type="text" id="tag" #tag="form" [ng-form-control]="playerForm.controls['tag']"  placeholder="Tag"/>

        <span *ng-if="tag.control.hasError('required') && !tag.control.pristine">Tag is required</span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" [class.has-error]="!playerForm.find('name').valid && playerForm.find('name').touched">
        <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
            <label for="name">Player Name: </label>
        </div>

        <input type="text" id="name" #name="form" [ng-form-control]="playerForm.controls['name']" placeholder="Player Name" />

        <span *ng-if="name.control.hasError('required') && !name.control.pristine">Player Name is required</span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" [class.has-error]="!playerForm.find('score').valid && playerForm.find('score').touched">
        <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
            <label for="score">Score: </label>
        </div>

        <input type="number" id="score" #score="form" [ng-form-control]="playerForm.controls['score']" value="0" min="0" max="200" />

        <span *ng-if="score.control.hasError('required') && !score.control.pristine">Score is required</span>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        Add Player
    </button>
</form>
```

So how can i reset the value of the control?

Comment: Try [`updateValue`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.40/modules/angular2/src/core/forms/model.ts#L172)

Answer (score 2):

To reset the form the easiest way is rebuild the form builder.
  After clicking the add player button

```
this.playerForm = this.builder.group({
        'name': [...],
        'tag': [...],
        'score': [...]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(let c in form.controls) {
    form.controls[c].updateValue('');
};
```

Comment: To avoid deletion, please explain your answer.

Comment: The answer kind of explains it self, IMO... for loop calling each form control's updateValue to an empty string.... seems self explanatory enough to me :)
I might say, though, that there should be a hasOwnProperty check inside the for loop though.

Answer (score -1):

According to angular 2 docs it looks like the updateValue has some params like only self and emitEvent which seem to handle the validation reset. Have you tried that?

Comment: add some more details