# How to reset a ngFormModel and lose the validation errors in Angular 2 Typescript?

Tags: forms, validation, typescript, angular, model-driven

I have a ngFormModel with a ngControl textbox.

```
    <form [ngFormModel]="addFriendForm" (ngSubmit)="create()" 
                    class="form-vertical" #friendForm="ngForm">
```

On dirty an error message is displayed.

```
 <div [hidden]="id.valid || id.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
                Invalid ID
                 </div>
```

On submitting the form, I want to reset the form. Currently I am setting 
like this

```
this.addFriendForm.controls["id"].updateValue(null);
```

This makes the form show the validation error on screen.

I am not able to avoid this error message on resetting the value to null. Is there a way to programmatically reset the form ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset form validation on submission of the form in ANGULAR 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34608361/how-to-reset-form-validation-on-submission-of-the-form-in-angular-2)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33084280/how-to-reset-control-value

Comment: k thank you @GünterZöchbauer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining the controlGroup once again after submitting will solves this one.I found the answer from this [link](https://github.com/ajtowf/ng2_play/blob/master/app/components/todo/todo.ts)

```
this.testForm= this.fb.group({
            id: ["", Validators.required],
            name: ["", Validators.required]
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported. A workaround is to recreate the form.